# Which tool to remove this bottom bracket nut - photo provided

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

[image: bottom bracket non-chain side]

[image: bottom bracket chain side]

I have an Apollo Transfer 21 inch frame and need to remove the bottom bracket.  It seems to be a screw in bottom bracket.

I am new to bicycle maintenance by the way.  I tried a 26mm spanner to remove the 6-sided nut in the bottom bracket non-chain side photo.  I was able to remove but I think I tightened too much and need to remove again and using the 26mm spanner is not easy.  So I am wondering if I am using the wrong tool.

What tool do I need to take off the nut in the bottom bracket non-chain side photo?  A 25mm spanner is too small.  A 26mm spanner is a bit too big.

the other side of the bottom bracket is as per other photo - bottom bracket chain side.  What too to remove that side?  I have a feeling it might be a Park tool HCW-4?  But not sure.

A related question, where do I find the exact manual for this bike?  There is a generic Apollo manual available - but is very vague on everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cup on the chain side is called the "fixed cup."

You should be aware that it is a left thread and will unscrew clockwise on this bike. For service, this is often left in place.

The non-chain side is the adjustable cup, used to set the preload on the bearing (adjust for play). There is a lockring around the outside. Generally to set the preload,you loosen the splined lockring, use your spanner to gently set the preload, then lock off your lockring again. You can also remove this side to grease the bearings. I use a lockring tool to fit the lockring, Park make a few in different sizes (mine is a Lazer). I use a very high quality adjustable spanner for most of these but sometimes the flat spanner made for the purpose happens to fit. often it doesn't or the cup uses a pin spanner. Anyway, if it's neither 25 nor 26mm, it's probably an imperial size.

There is no manual for the specific bike but any cycle repair manual eg Richard's or Zinn, even one from the 1980s and before, will cover this bb system.

Comment: Of course, it must be 1 inch which is 25.4mm

Answer (score 2):

Noise has it right - the lockring on the non-drive side (ie the left side of the bike) needs to be loosened first - it will be "normal right hand thread"

You could use a hammer and punch in the notches but that tends to mushroom metal.  I'd use large plumber's pliers, aka slipjaw pliers or waterpump pliers, or there's probably a correct tool I don't own.

Then the hex nutted part should be easier to undo.  Its easy to round off corners, so first clean the edges of paint and dirt to try and get a snug fit from your tool on the hex.

Be warned that there's probably loose/dirty ball bearings inside this, so once you get the cup off they may rain out.

Your drive-side cup doesn't appear to have any flats on it - I can't see how that would unthread but once the axle is removed out the left hand side, it may be more obvious.  Drive side cup should be threaded into the frame with a  **left-hand thread** which is opposite, so clockwise to undo.

[image]

Everyone should have a pair of these - a $10 set is quite adequate.   You can use a rag in the jaws to reduce marring of parts.

Comment: Park HCW-5 is the correct tool you don't own.

Comment: @whatsisname thank you - yep I have the HCW-4 and the HCW-11 but not that one.   https://www.parktool.com/en-int/product/crank-and-bottom-bracket-wrench-hcw-5